# "Отстаивая свои земли – осаждая города агрессоров" - можно ли и что со знаками?

Tags: пунктуация

> И даже в древности, отстаивая свои земли – осаждая города агрессоров,
>   на заре своей истории, сербы говорили жителям: «Выходите, сейте и
>   жните, в качестве дани мы возьмем лишь половину»…

Может, просто: *отстаивая **и** осаждая?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы убрала тире:

*И даже в древности, **отстаивая свои земли, осаждая города агрессоров, на заре своей истории,** сербы говорили жителям: «Выходите, сейте и жните, в качестве дани мы возьмем лишь половину»…*

Получится обособленный **однородный** ряд обстоятельств со значением времени (когда отстаивали, когда осаждали осаждали, на заре истории).